# What happens to models with BelongsTo and hasOne relationship setup?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, models, foreign-key-relationship, has-one

What happens when two models are associated with a belongsTo and a hasOne relationship at the same time?
Does the framework detect this situation to avoid retrieving too much data?

EDIT: CakePHP specifically, although what other frameworks do would be helpful, too.

Comment: Chustar or Thorpe, did you learn more about this situation that you can share with us?  I'm confused about using hasOne and belongsTo at the same time.  The docs don't show doing this, and I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: @Ray K, see the answer below. Essentially, the framework wouldn't load all the data available unless I ask for it. 

This way, the burden is not me to avoid circular requests. But if I do make circular requests, it will try to fulfill them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most frameworks do lazy loading of data, that is, data is retrieved only when the object property is accessed.

Comment: So most frameworks would work fine with this unless I tried something like a `print_r()` ?

Comment: if print_r() is limited to a single record, then only that record will be retrieved. on the other hand, if print_r() tries to display a relationship, behind the scenes, the pdo cursors of all relevant associated objects will activate and retrieve the necessary data. i sure hope you're not using print_r() for a large multi-dimensional array of objects.